# String split fixed on CSV

Tags: r, string, split

I have a CSV with 22 cols, within each cell is complied data eg(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.) sep by commas. Installing the stringr package I can use the str_split_fixed() function to my data.

I can perform

> str_split_fixed(a$col_1, “,”,12)

to split a single col, but I want to apply this function to all columns of CSV to save typing out the above code 22 times...
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What are you doing with these values after you split them? And the columns of your CSV file are separated by commas, but your fields also have comma separators? I would be helpful in include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: How do you want to arrange them? In a list form? In a table? etc

Comment: Table form so then I can output to a new CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply` family of functions will apply across a dataset:

```
lapply(a,function(x) str_split_fixed(x, “,”,12))
```

will return a list with the results of splitting each column in a separate list object.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen lapply used but was missing the function(x) command.